# Identification of a shrub

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

[image]white variegated leaves
Fall blooms of crimson red dainty flowers
Currently in Zone 6[image]

[image: Shrub with white variegated leaves and fall blooming dainty crimson flowers, Windsor, Ontario, Canada]

Comment: Can you  add another photo showing the whole plant so we can see height, spread, and growth habit please?

Comment: I added two more pictures. I thought it was some kind of euonymous but could not find anything like this.

Comment: Definitely not a euonymus, but where are you in the world, somewhere without hard winters?

Comment: I forgot to ask, does it keep its leaves in winter?

Comment: Plant is located in Windsor, Ontario, Canada.  This shrub dies back in the winter, leaves fall off, and then it comes back in the spring.

Answer (score 2):

a very nice persicaria.
there is a lot of cultivars.
This is a Persicaria virginiana , probably Persicaria virginiana 'Variegata'.

http://www.biobrave.com/index.php/plant/255?name=Persicaria+virginiana+%27Variegata%27

close-up: https://plantlust.com/plants/persicaria-virginiana-variegata-group/images/54469/